# Implement a function that rounds a number to the nearest number that is divisible by X

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

I have the following code.

Implement the function nearestX that rounds a number to the nearest number that is divisible by X. For example, if 13 is being rounded to the nearest 5 it rounds to 15. If the number is exactly between two possible numbers, it should be rounded up.

```
def nearestX(num, x):
    if x == 0:
        return num
    remainder = abs(num % x)
    print(remainder)
    if remainder == 0:
        return num
    if num < 0:
        return -(abs(num) - remainder)
    else:
        return num + x - remainder
```

But it doesn't work for `nearest(12,5)` for example which should give `10` as this is closer than `15` but it returns 15 instead.

Comment: What is the expected output for `nearestX(1, 2)`?

Comment: the expected output is 2, between the equally distant choice of 0 or 2 it will round up

Comment: You may want to update the question with a selection rule when multiple rounded values are of equal distance from `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the given number to a `decimal.Decimal` object so that you can specify the type of rounding based on whether the number of positive or negative when you convert it back to an integer with the `to_integral_exact` method:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_HALF_DOWN
def nearestX(num, x):
    return (Decimal(num) / x).to_integral_exact(
        rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN if num < 0 else ROUND_HALF_UP) * x
```

Comment: It works in most cases but not for example, nearestX(-6,4) which returns -8 instead of -4 and nearest(45,10) which returns 40 instead of 50... I forgot to say that I wanted it to round UP when it is a tie between the nearest above and below options.

Comment: Note that your expected output of `-4` for `nearestX(-6,4)` is actually a result of rounding *down* rather than up, since rounding up actually means to round away from zero, which is why in my updated answer I'm rounding down for negative ties in order to achieve your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `nearestX(num, x)` is either `x * (num // x)` or `(x + 1) * (num // x)`. Accounting for the round up rule, we have:

```
def nearestX(num, x):
  d = num // x
  a = d * x
  b = a + x
  if b - num <= num - a:
    return b
  else:
    return a
```

e.g.

```
for i in range(10):
  print(i, nearestX(i, 3))
0 0
1 0
2 3
3 3
4 3
5 6
6 6
7 6
8 9
9 9
```